# Discord bot crash

Tags: python, discord, chatbot

I've watched A LOT of toturials and all of them use: client = discord.Client()
It it gives me an error when i try to run the code. The error says that it's the: "client = discord.Client()" that's the problem. It says that there's a missing argument: 'intents'

I have used the same lowercase lettes in all.
I'm using repl.it python
What should i do??   [The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A66mN.png)      [The code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0C3Q.png)

Comment: Hi, please read [ask] and copy paste the code using formatting tools instead of a link to an image, it will help us copy pasting your code and reproduce your error

Comment: And don't edit title to add irrelevant stuff like sad smiley.

Comment: Perhaps consider looking at the documentation? The [quickstart](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) docs have using intents at the very start and show you how you should create a `discord.Client` instance. Better to use the docs and the guides rather than watching what I am assuming is outdated tutorials.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "It says that there's a missing argument: 'intents'... What should I do??" Did you try [copying and pasting the error message into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=missing+argument%3A+%27intents%27)? For future questions, please read [ask], and [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to find answers yourself before asking. When you do post, show code and errors [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Above all, note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score -1):

The error is being thrown, due to you not setting the intents for the bot, one of the ways to do it is using discord.Intents().all(), for example:

```
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)
```

Note: This is not the ideal solution, ideally you would want to know all the intents that your bot needs and only set those. (.default)